# PHP: Embedding website into page

Tags: php, embed

I want to call a website and embed it into a table cell. I have no problem getting the request for the site or the url from the database. But when I embed it, it jumbles it and puts it all over the place or doesn't open the entire page.

I have:

```
$remote = fopen("http://www.theothersite.com/list.php", "r");
fpassthru($remote);
```

Are there any other cleaner solutions?

iframe shows up blank:
echo `'<iframe src="'.$row[$url].'" width="100%" />'`;

```
        $url = 'URL';
        $tag = 'Tag';
        $id = 'P_Id';

        $query = "SELECT * FROM web_db WHERE Tag = '" . $userTag . "' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if($result) 
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
           {
              echo 'ID:' . $row[$id] . '<br>';
              echo 'URL: ' . $row[$url] . '<br>';
              echo 'Tag:' . $row[$tag] . '<p>';


        //    $remote = fopen($row[$url],"r");
        //    fpassthru($remote);

            echo '<iframe src="'.$row[$url].'" width="100%" />';
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what prevents you from trying a HTML solution ?

Put an iframe inside the table with src equal to the website URL .
If you do not have to pre-process the data of the other site, or do not need to
hide the other site url, then iframe is a good solution.
See example : http://jsfiddle.net/c43zH/

Comment: echo '<iframe src="'.$row[$url].'" width="100%" />';

Comment: @Chris: Can we have your entire code with the `<iframe>`? Because it does work, that's what it's for. Also, I don't think `<iframe>` is self-closing, is it?

Answer (score 2):

why don't you try with iframe ? Something like:

```
<td><iframe src='http://www.theothersite.com/list.php'></iframe></td>
```

otherwise you have some tags like html and body inside a td and this can be confusing for the browser. Also consider that your loaded page use the styles of the wrapper page

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use an iframe, it is designed to do the thing you need.

[Here's an example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)